# React- Destruct State error in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement a react component for AutoComplete by referring to a Tutorial.I am using Typescript for my development. When I try to destruct the state inside the render suggestions method the TSLint compiler shows an error saying **'Property Suggestions does not exist on type {}'**. Could any one help me to overcome this. It is a big big help.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Autocomplete extends React.Component<{},{}> {
    items: string[];  
    constructor( props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {   
            suggestions :[],
        };
        this.items =['David','Damian','sara'];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <input
                type="text" onChange={this.onTextChanged}        
            />  
                {this.renderSuggestions()}                
            </div>
        );
    }  

    onTextChanged = (e) =>{
        console.log(e.target.value);    
        const value = e.target.value;  
        let suggestions =[];
        if(value.legth>0){
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`,'i');
            suggestions = this.items.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
        }
        this.setState(()=> ({suggestions}));
    }

    renderSuggestions() {
        const {suggestions } = this.state;
        if(suggestions.length === 0){
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                {suggestions.map((item)=> <li>{item}</li>)}   
            </ul>       
        );
    }   
}
```

**[EDIT : Attached the Screen Capture]**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Considering all the comments and bit of struggling and some readings I made it work. Thank you for all your suggestions.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Suggestions } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

export interface IServiceState {
    suggestions ?: string []
}

export default class Autocomplete extends React.Component<{},IServiceState> {
    items =['David','Damian','sara'];
    constructor( props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {   
            suggestions : [],
        };

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <input
                type="text" onChange={this.onTextChanged}        
            />  
                {this.renderSuggestions()}                
            </div>
        );
    }  

    onTextChanged = (e) =>{
        console.log(e.target.value);    
        const value = e.target.value;  
        let suggestions :string[];     
        if(value.length>0){
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`,'i');
            suggestions = this.items.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
            console.log(suggestions);
        }
        //this.setState(()=> ({suggestions1}));
       //this.setState()
        this.setState({suggestions : suggestions});
    }

    renderSuggestions() {
       const suggestions :string[]= this.state.suggestions;
       console.log('render Suggestions');
       console.log(this.state.suggestions);
       console.log('render1 Suggestions');
        if(Suggestions.length === 0){
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                {suggestions.map((item)=> <li>{item}</li>)}   
            </ul>       
        );
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was in your

`if(value.legth>0){}`, you missed `n` for `length`. It was just a typo error.

Also I tried the typescript version and this was the only mistake

[Link to typescript version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mz45bm)

Updated working code is

```
 import * as React from 'react';

export default class Autocomplete extends React.Component {
    items=[];  
    constructor( props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {   
            suggestions :[],
        };
        this.items =['David','Damian','sara'];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <input
                type="text" onChange={this.onTextChanged}        
            />  
                {this.renderSuggestions()}                
            </div>
        );
    }  

    onTextChanged = (e) =>{
        console.log(e.target.value);    
        const value = e.target.value;  
        let suggestions =[];
        if(value.length>0){
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`,'i');
            suggestions = this.items.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
        }
        this.setState(()=> ({suggestions}));
    }

    renderSuggestions() {
        const {suggestions } = this.state;
        if(suggestions.length === 0){
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                {suggestions.map((item)=> <li>{item}</li>)}   
            </ul>       
        );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to me about the typo. I still have the error in the renderSuggestions method. Its at the first line.

Comment: Strange, but I checked in the typescript fiddle also, no such error in console. could please check the react version and can you add a screenshot

Comment: Yes true. React version in my Package.json is  "react": "15.4.2",
"react-dom": "15.4.2". Well I am not sure it happens due to typescript. Because destruction should work with ES6.

Comment: @SPKan I came across several search and concluded that, every element on state should have its type defined. Create an interface and define its type there, like `interface state = {
suggestions: array<any>
}`. I dont know the exact syntax, but try

Comment: Thank you for your support. Yes I hope I did the same. Which should be the only way to overcome it.

Answer (score 1):

You specify in your component that the state is of type `{}` by doing `React.Component<{}>`. You can usually avoid this by letting typescript infer the state but it has a bit of a problem doing that when the state is assigned inside the constructor. You can usually fix these by assigning them directly as fields inside the class like

```
export default class Autocomplete extends React.Component {
    items = ['David','Damian','sara']
    state = { suggestions :[] }
    // rest of your component here
}
```

You can do this in your current class because you don't use the constructor for anything other than setting state, but if that's not an option, you can make sure typescript understands the state properly by assigning it as an explicit generic argument for your component like such.

```
interface AutocompleteState {
  suggestions: Suggestion[]
}

export default class Autocomplete extends React.Component<AutocompleteState> {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Even though I followed your first suggestion I still get the error in the renderSuggestions() method when I am destruct the state. "error TS2459: Type '{}' has no property 'suggestions' and no string index signature."